# Airflow: How to make an object public in s3 bucket after daily refresh

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, airflow, bucket

i am deleting and creating the same file(s3 object) every day and this file needs to be accessed by vendors from different company. after every run the object was by default to private. 
Is there a way to automatically set this bucket object to public or whitelist certain IP's? I am using airflow.

searched the documentation in airflow but not helpful

1. Some operator to make bucket public   or
2. some operator to whitelist ip's

Answer (score 2):

- I recon this is not really an Airflow query but more of an AWS SDK / boto3 query
- Airflow natively has no `Operator` or [`Hook`](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#hooks) with the said functionality; you'll have to cook-up some code to achieve this

---

- You can `boto3`'s [S3 Client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html) (which is also [used by Airflow's `S3Hook`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/S3_hook.py#L67)) to achieve this
- In particular, you can exploit [`put_object_acl(..)`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object_acl) method

here's a sample code-snippet

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import BaseClient
s3_client: BaseClient = boto3.client("s3", region_name="ap-southeast-1")
s3_client.put_object_acl(ACL="public-read", Bucket="my-bucket", Key="key/of/my/object")
```

---

For implementing the above code-snippet in an Airflow task, there are a few options

1. Just use a `PythonOperator` / any other operator that you are using and embed the above code-snippet within rest of your code (simplest)
2. Write a `CustomS3Hook` extending Airflow's `S3Hook` and put this functionality there (good from re-usability perspective, but a bit overkill)
3. Put this snippet in some `aws_utils.py` file and use it across your workflow wherever needed (re-usable, and not too complicated)